# Re-open child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one Main form and two types of child form

> MainForm
>   ChildFormA - unique
>   ChildFormB - have multiple forms of this type

I create ChildFormA with:

```
ChildFormA form1 = new ChildFormA();
form1.MdiParent = this;
form1.Show();
```

But when i close it with:

```
form1.Close();
```

I can't re-open it.
I've already read some tips that I can Hide this form instead or closing it. But the X button still closes the form.
How to re-open or how to prevent the X button to close and simple hide it?

Comment: The "X" button will always close the form unless you handle the FormClosing Event and hide the form instead of disposing of it, the problem there is you will be left with no way to close the form unless you gave the user the option to Close or Hide the form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want your child form to remain in its state, you have to subscribe to the `FormClosing` event and set the `Cancel` property of the event argument to `true`.

```
public ChildForm()
{
    ...
    FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(ChildForm_FormClosing);
}


void ChildForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

Keep in mind, that you're form will not get disposed, if you don't add more logic to this.

Otherwise, you can just create a new instance of it.

Comment: +1, yes use .Hide() instead of .Close() if you want to re-show the form.

Comment: I'm new at C# and Winforms.
I understand that this code should be at my ChildFormA.cs, right?
How to associate the X button with the FormClosing class?

Comment: @MatthiasKoch Thanks. But placing the FormClosing += FormClosing int the ChildForm class, I get an error:
"Error 5 Cannot assign to 'FormClosing' because it is a 'method group' C:\Dropbox\Automazer\Automazer v0.01\Automazer v0.01\FormAddressList.cs 18 13 Automazer v0.01
"

Comment: @AgentBretman: try `FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(FormClosing);` instead

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: Am I doing something stupid? Here is the full code of that child:
http://pastebin.com/3hZ2Kpij

Comment: @AgentBretman: try this: open your form in the designer. select the form itself. go to the event list, and double-click the `FormClosing` event. paste the code (`e.Cancel = true; Hide();`) from my post.

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: I never used the event list. And so simple... Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think it was due to the naming of the event handler method :\ @AgentBretman: can you accept when it worked? just reached the rep cap :D

Answer (score 3):

Create a new instance of `ChildFormA`.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a Child Form only Once .

```
ChildFormA form1 = new ChildFormA();
if(form1 == null)
{
 form1.MdiParent = this;
 form1.Show();
}
else
 form1.Show();
```

than you should use Matthias Koch solution ,on child Forms

```
void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

Also Keep `ChilFormA` as a **MDI Class Field** ,so you won't lose Ref. to it.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent the form from closing is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx). I would also advice hide, but maybe it works to set visible to false...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Singleton pattern in for this Form.

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Look at the 4th approach

Then you would access it using the static instance instead of creating a new one.
You still need Matthias Koch solution ,on child Forms

```
void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

If you need further help with the Singleton pattern, please say so.